# Why `std::throw_with_nested()` silently falls back to throwing the parameter unchanged if it doesn't satisfy the requirements?

Tags: c++

Normally `std::throw_with_nested(x)` throws a class derived from both `x` and `std::nested_exception`.

This [only happens if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested):

> `std::decay<T>::type` is a non-final non-union class type that is neither `std::nested_exception` nor derived from `std::nested_exception`

Otherwise the argument is thrown unchanged.

For example, `std::throw_with_nested(42)` throws an `int`.

Intuitively I would expect to get a `static_assert`ion in this case, or better a SFINAE-friendly error. I'm unsure why a sane person would want the parameter to be thrown unchanged.

What's the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: From the proposal: "[Rather than ban \[types which cannot be derived from\] with a requires clause, it is preferred to simply throw the exception as provided in these cases, so support use generic code](http://isocpp.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2559.htm)."

Comment: @RaymondChen A "generic code", huh. :| I have a hard time imaging what kind of code would need it.

Answer (score 1):

It always throws something that can still be caught by `catch(decltype(x))`.

I think that's desirable because re-throwing an in-flight exception object is perfectly valid, it would be obtuse to require changing things between the `std::throw_with_nested(x)` and the `catch(std::nested_exception&)`.

Comment: *"changing things between the `std::throw_with_nested(x)` and the `catch(std::nested_exception&)`"* Can you elaborate on this? From my understanding, the parameter of `throw_with_nested` is not supposed to be the catched exception (that one is found automatically), but a new exception, the type of which is normally known at compile-time. Why would you want to handle `std::nested_exception` differently from other exception types?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh yes, it's more limited than what I thought. The situation I'm thinking of is where you had a template with a `throw some_expression` where `some_expression` depends on the template parameters, and now want it to be `std::throw_with_nested(some_expression)`. Pretty contrived, and throwing non-class objects is somewhat esoteric, I agree.